# Probability to reach final state

Tags: probability

Let $~~m,n>0~~$  be some positive integers. We have some system of states. Each state is pair $~~(i,k)~~$ where $~~0\leq i \leq m~~$  and  $~~0\leq k \leq n~~$. Starting state is $~~(m,n)~~$. For each state $~~(i,k)~~$ we're given three probablities  $~~p_{ik},q_{ik}, r_{ik}$:
$p_{ik} + q_{ik} + r_{ik} = 1$

$p~~$ that next state will be $~~(i-2,k)$, $~~p=0~~$ if $~~i < 2$

$q~~$ that next state will be $~~(i,k-1)$,  $~~q=0~~$ if $~~k < 1$

$r~~$ that next step will be $~~(i,k)$,  $~~r=0~~$ if $~~k < 2$

For states $(1,0)$ and $(0,k)$ for any allowed $k$ by definition we have $q=1$. State $(1,0)$ is considered bad and states $(0,k)$ are considered good. How can i calculate the probability to reach good state? Thanks in advance!

P.S.
Originally it was a programming problem so i decided to use dynamic programming for recalculating the probability to reach final state for any state and then summing them up. I'm not sure that this solution is correct and i don't underestand how to "use" the probability of staying in the same state.

Comment: There is an error here...What if I reach a $(k,0)$ state? then $q=0$

Comment: Thank you. I've changed the statement.

Comment: In that case, you will always reach the final state some time or the other. What probability do you want to calculate exactly?

Comment: Suppose my starting state is (2,1) with $~~p=1/3,~~q = 2/3,~~r=0~~$. Then i have probaility 1/3 to come to good state and with probability 2/3 i won't.

Comment: Why do we have $q = 1$ when the state is (0, 10), for instance? $k$ is not $\lt 2$, so it seems that we should be able to reach (0, 10) as well.

Comment: That's part of definition of this system.